# google tag manager event : 2 same CTA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'd like to track a form CTA confirmation in GTM. There are 2 forms, Urls are the same, CTA are the same, but I'd like to collect those 2 CTAs in different events.
I did a GTM trigger with : when click ID = my CTA, I collect the information "when a user click to that CTA, an event is sent", but i'd like to collect that information, based on my form version, which is only differ in two areas of the website :
- In the  Here is unique 
- In the script :

```
var comparator = new Comparator();
comparator.init( {  'uniqKey' : "azeaze",
                    'surveyName' : "Here is unique",
                    'guidanceMode': false,
                    'url' : "/surveyProgress",
                    'save' : "/leadSave",
                        });
```

How can I consider in GTM the trigger :
When the CTA ID = XXX 
AND 
my 'surveyName = 1'
Fire an event.
If i would do that I could use 'surveyName = 2' for the other form.
The idea is, with the same CTA but with other HTML element in the "background" to fire 2 different events.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger configuration click on plus sign next to your rules. This works as AND operator so all rules will have to be true. That way you can have 2 triggers - one for each CTA. For example:

[image]

You will have to setup "surveyName" variable. It could be either dataLayer variable or global JS variable, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you Matus, I understand the approach. 
If I don't have yet a dataLayer variable or JS variable, can I use something like creating a gtm custom JS function to collect the information from that script I described before ?
I mean, it could be technically possible to use what I have yet to achieve what I'd like ? Or should I do dataLayer update.(If I can avoid it's better)

Comment: It's completly up to you how to collect surveyName variable. As you said it can be JS custom function that returns the inforamtion.